# standard way to find service (open port in local network)

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, network-programming, udp

I want implement auto connection of two of my programs,
that are in the same local network.

Program `A` open TCP/IP socket for listening on some predefined port.
Program `B` should find out if there is program `A` in local network.

What standard way to achieve this, without configuration of third party software (I mean dns servers or some other resolving software)?

I found [ssdp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) protocol, is this what I looking for, or I just need scan all local network IP range for open ports?

Answer (score 1):

SSDP or zeroconf would be the fastest solution and by far better that scanning for open ports.

Scanning for open ports would take far more time as you will have to wait until timeout to know that the port is closed.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly should I use zeroconf or SSDP?

Comment: i would recommend zeroconf as it supports network discovery feature such as UPnP and Multicast DNS as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking

Comment: In wikipedia `SSDP` is paragraph in `zeroconf` description, so it is not clear is it possible `ssdp` vs `zeroconf` compare.

Comment: I do agree that wikipedia's article is not very clear and there is not much on the internet that clearly differentiates both protocol. 

I think that both SSDP and zeroconf share similarities in terms of feature. It would be like two similar protocol developed by two different organisation.